# Python-библиотеки для распознавания речи offline

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Ищу библиотеку для распознавания русской речи (ASR) в аудиозаписях длительностью до 30 минут.
Работать нужно offline (т.е. без использования API - сервисов).

Что было найдено и какие возникли проблемы:

1. Kaldi, а точнее враппер на python под названием pykaldi. Честно, не смог разобраться в ней. Насколько я понял, реализованы математические инструменты обработки звука, но знаком с ними поверхностно, так что буду рад хорошей инструкции по использованию.
2. PocketSphinx. Тут проблема оказалась в качестве распознавания - оно было отвратительным. Возникли вопросы: работает ли вообще эта библиотека с длинными аудио? (Видел бесчисленное множество работы с ограниченным набором команд. Например, для умного дома). В [туторе](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialadapt/#recording-your-adaptation-data) есть описание "Адаптации" акустической модели языка, повлияет ли она на качество распознавания?

Собственно, есть ли ещё варианты? Я никогда не исключаю, что проморгал что-то очевидное.

P.S. Имеется обширный набор данных вида Аудио + Текст из этого аудио, который, возможно, может быть применён для настройки точности (Например, для русской модели в pocketsphinx

Comment: Так что вообще лучше распознаёт? калди или сфинкс? А как по задержкам? Автор отпишись пожалуйста, к чему в итоге пришёл?

Comment: Vosk лучше всего распознаёт ;)

Answer (score 10):

Для декодирования можно использовать библиотеку [vosk-api](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api). Устанавливается просто - `pip install vosk`.

Русскую модель для Kaldi скачать [здесь](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/doc/models.md).

Примерно вот так выглядит код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import sys
import os
import wave

if not os.path.exists("model-en"):
    print ("Please download the model from https://github.com/alphacep/kaldi-android-demo/releases and unpack as 'model-en' in the current folder.")
    exit (1)

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
if wf.getnchannels() != 1 or wf.getsampwidth() != 2 or wf.getcomptype() != "NONE":
    print ("Audio file must be WAV format mono PCM.")
    exit (1)

model = Model("model-en")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, wf.getframerate())

while True:
    data = wf.readframes(1000)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
        print(rec.Result())
    else:
        print(rec.PartialResult())

print(rec.FinalResult())
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку.
Хотелось бы уточнить, в py-kaldi-asr сказано, что используются "kaldi's online nnet3-chain decoders", это зашитое внутрь библиотеки обращение к api Калди?

Comment: Да, можно использовать программный интерфейс Kaldi